# CQ bundle throws exception: only a type can be imported

Tags: osgi, aem

I have created a sample bundle in CQ5's CRXDE. The process as given on [the tutorial](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/core/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde_lite.html#Managing%20a%20Bundle) was followed to the word.

But when I run the page, it just throws an exception

```
    An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
    Only a type can be imported. com.mycompany.test.HelloWorld resolves to a package
```

The jsp is as below:

```
<%@ page import="com.mycompany.test.HelloWorld"%><%
%><%@ include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><% HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();%><%
%>
<html>
<body>
<b><%= hello.getString() %></b><br>
</body>
</html>
```

The HelloWorld.java is as follows:

package com.mycompany.test;

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public String getString(){
    return "Say Hello to my little friend !!";
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what might be wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your .bnd file contains the below lines. If not present, you can add them and then build the bundle again.

```
Export-Package: *
Import-Package: *
Private-Package: *
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when your class is not visible in the code.

Make sure 
1. Your bundle in the felix (/system/console/bundles) is in **active** state (shouldn't be in resolved / installed).
2. Your bundle has exported the package com.mycompany.* or *